# How to perform variable assignment using dataframe name as variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a written a python function that takes a data frame as one of the arguments. Below is the simplified version of the function:

```
def cat_update(df_to_update, df_source, cat_lst, con_lst):
    try:
        for cat, con in itertools.product(cat_lst, con_lst):
            df_to_update.at[cat,  con] = df_source.at[cat,  con]
```

Below is how I am calling this function:

```
cat_update(df_templete1, raw_source, cat_lst, con_lst)
```

Now, I need to scale my code where there can be multiple source data frames (`raw_source`)

How do I specify a variable here so that instead of specifying the actual data frame value I can change it as per the requirement?

I tried specifying assigning the value of the variable as follows:

```
raw_source = 'df_source_1'
```

But in this case, it goes as a string and not as a data frame hence the function is not able to evaluate it as per expectations. In short, I need to change it from `str` to `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`

More information:
I call the above function inside a for loop:

```
for n in range(len(df_config)):
    cat_lst = df_config.at[n,'category'].split(",")
    con_lst = df_config.at[n,'country'].split(",")
    raw_source = df_config.at[n,'Raw source']
    energy_source = df_config.at[n,'Energy source']
```

Hence the source data frame is picked up automatically from user input which is saved in the `df_config`.

Comment: Could you please also add `raw_cat_update` method?

Comment: I updated the call function name. It was a typo.

Comment: Don't pass the variable name -- that has no meaning at all at runtime.  Instead, just pass the dataframe itself.  Use a `dict` to map a name to a dataframe if you need to, but that seems unlikely in this case.

Comment: i have multiple source dataframes. If i use the above, i will have to write same function multiple times like: ```cat_update(df_templete1, df_source_1, cat_lst, con_lst)```; ```cat_update(df_templete1, df_source_2, cat_lst, con_lst)```
Also, which source is to be used is conditional so I was trying to write a generic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary like this: `{"data_frame_name" : data_frame}`, so that you can access each data_frame by it's name, and assume we have a `data_src_1` data, like below:

```py
data_src_1 = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df_source_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_src_1)
raw_sources = {"df_source_1" : df_source_1}    # You can have other dataframes here
```

Pass the name of data frame you want `df_source` to the `cat_update` method, and edit the method like this:

```py
raw_sources = {"df_source_1" : df_source_1, ...}
def cat_update(df_to_update, df_source, cat_lst, con_lst):
    try:
        for cat, con in itertools.product(cat_lst, con_lst):
            df_to_update.at[cat,  con] = raw_sources[df_source].at[cat,  con]
```

---

However, you could just pass the data frame such as `df_source_1` it self to the method, but in the above snippet, you can have all data frames altogether in one dictionary (`raw_sources`).